# Share Artifact Download Url with external users

Tags: azure-devops

We have a build pipeline on Azure Pipelines. We mainly use the REST API to start builds etc. When we create a build artifact we can obtain a downloadUrl.

We wish to share with external users, however we only wish to give them permission to only download the artifact, no other permissions to view the project or anything else. Is this possible to setup a user with only permission to download the build.

Comment: build artifact or feed package?

Comment: @4c74356b41        build artifact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your only option is creating an intermediate api that would expose only build artifacts download link. you cant be that granular with Azure DevOps build permissions. If you can view - you can view everything related to build, not only artifacts.